# Puppeteer is failing to upload a file with TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, jestjs, puppeteer

I've followed the documentation and examples on how to use Puppeteer's `uploadFile()` method.

However, I keep receiving this error message `Evaluation failed: TypeError: Failed to fetch`

I can't figure out why I can't automate this upload. I have a file saved in my repo that I am trying to upload.

Here is a snippet of `uploadFile()` code.

```
    await page.waitForSelector('input[type="file"]');


    const fileInput = await page.$('input[type="file"]');

    const filePath = 'path-to-my-file';

    await fileInput.uploadFile(filePath);
```

Any pointers on where I should look?

*** "Solution" ***
Looks like Puppeteer version 2.1.1 may have issues indicated by this GitHub ticket. https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5503
There are several other open tickets related to the same issue if you check the repo (as of 03/23/20).

In that ticket, the user downgraded to 2.0.0 and the attachment feature works.

Comment: Make sure the path is correctly resolved. At the top of your script, add `const Path = require('path');`, and in the script, do `const filePath = Path.join(__dirname, 'path-to-file-relative-to-this-script.jpg');`. It works for me. If you're on Unix, make sure the file has access rights

Comment: @blex Just tried this, but I'm still getting the `Evaluation failed: TypeError: Failed to fetch` error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Puppeteer version 2.1.1 may have issues indicated by this GitHub ticket. https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5503

In that ticket, the user downgraded to 2.0.0 and the attachment feature works.